# Permission Denied for mkdir() php in Docker

Tags: php, docker, mkdir

When i Run my php code in docker for mkdir it says this in the browser

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 9

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 12
```

I have been searching but can't get any suitable source for my use. How can i allow docker to give permission to my php or what is the solution?

Here is my php code

```
<?php
$postk = "1220";
$root = "login/";
$room_id = "foile";
$NewRoot = "movie";

if (!file_exists($root . $postk)) {
    $dirPathp = $root . $postk;
    $resultp = mkdir($dirPathp, 0777, true);

    $dirPathpr = $root . $postk . "/" . $room_id;
    $resultpr = mkdir($dirPathpr, 0777, true);

} else {
    $dirPathpr = $root . $postk . " / " . $room_id;
    $resultpr = mkdir($dirPathpr, 0777, true);
} ?>
```

Here is my Docker File

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

#Install git and Mysql Extensions for php

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY . /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 443/tcp
```

Here is Docker compose file

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  datafiles:

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    container_name: mysql6
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sopno_1818120**
      - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3306
      - TZ=Asia/Dhaka
    volumes:
      - datafiles:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always

  website:
    container_name: php6
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_DBPORT=3306
      - DB_USERNAME=sopnobari_tuneb
      - DB_PASSWORD=sopno_1818120**
      - DB_NAME=sopnobari_sopno
    ports:
      - "3050:80"
      - "3051:443"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Comment: Never expose passwords and such online, even if they are only used within dev environment. You get used to it and do it accidentally in production as well. It is also a bad example for others, even if YOU are totally sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution

in docker file add this code

```
COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www #this line after COPY
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 443/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes up because when you mount a volume into your docker container, the file and directory ownership of the host system passes along to the container aswell.

The files on your host system are owned by your user, PHP on the other hand runs on the user www-data. This differece causes the permission Problems.

Check [this](https://aschmelyun.com/blog/fixing-permissions-issues-with-docker-compose-and-php/) out to get rid of the problem.