# docker-compose & dockerfile - php mkdir permission denied

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, permission-denied

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    www:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.lamp
        ports: 
            - "${WEBSERVER_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
```

As you can see, the www folder in the same folder as the docker-compose.yml file is where the web code is hosted.

I have the following dockerfile (Dockerfile.lamp):

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql    

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      git \
      libicu-dev \
      zlib1g-dev \
      g++\
      libpq-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      git \
      zip \
      unzip

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl
```

All of it works, but one issue arose that in the www/index.php file I wrote

```
mkdir("testFolder", 0775, true);
```

giving me:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 1
```

Neither does mkdir("testFolder"); work

I tried adding the following line to the Docker.lamp file, without success:

```
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

What can I Do?
I already checked:

- [Permission Denied for mkdir() php in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303997/permission-denied-for-mkdir-php-in-docker)
- [Cannot create directory. Permission denied inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553074/cannot-create-directory-permission-denied-inside-docker-container)

Comment: Make sure docker itself is running as user, not as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely problem is that the directory you are mounting doesn't have the correct permissions for the `www-data` user inside the container to read. Running `chown` in the Dockerfile doesn't fix the problem because the mount doesn't exist during the build process.

One solution is to run chown on a running instance of the container with the volume mounted:

```bash
docker-compose run www chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

The reason running chown in the Dockerfile worked in the linked examples is because the files were being copied during the build, and then chown was being run on the copied versions.

Comment: This works, thanks! is there a method to automate this in a docker file or docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: You can create an entry script that runs `chown` that will run on the docker container's start up. The PHP Apache image has an example of this: https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/8.1/buster/apache

Comment: could you explain why this command has to be run from the docker-compose standpoint. Why can I not just run ```sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www``` Or, when the owner of folder ./www is ${USER}:${GROUP} can I not just add user www-data to ${GROUP} or would that not work?